# IndexError: list index out of range помогите исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, allure

```
import allure
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from typing import List


# import driver


def test_1(driver):
    # driver = WebDriver(executable_path='C://Users//vroma//Desktop//automation//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://ya.ru')
    search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="text"]')
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="search2__button"]//button[@type="submit"]')
    search_input.send_keys('uk.zhk.online')
    search_button.click()

    def check_results_count(driver):
        inner_search_results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="serp-item"]')
        return len(inner_search_results) >= 10

    with allure.step('количество результатов поиска'):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1, 0.5).until(check_results_count, 'количество результатов поиска')

    with allure.step('переходим по ссылке результата'):
        search_results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="serp-item"]')
        link = search_results[0].find_element_by_xpath('.//h2/a')
        link.click()


def test_2(driver):
    # driver = WebDriver(executable_path='C://Users//vroma//Desktop//automation//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe')
    # driver.get('https://ya.ru')
    search_input = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.form-group:nth-child(2) > .form-control')
    # (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-group:nth-child(2) > .form-control")
    # search_input.send_keys('+7 (911) 111-11-11')  # .send_keys(Keys.Enter)
    search_input[0].send_keys('+7 (911) 111-11-11')
    search_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.main-block')
    search_button.click()
    search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-group:nth-child(1) > .form-control')
    search_input[1].send_keys('qazwsx123')
    # search_input.send_keys('qazwsx123')
    search_input.send_keys_by_css_selector('.btn-signin')


driver = WebDriver(executable_path='C://Users//vroma//Desktop//automation//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe')
test_1(driver)
test_2(driver)

=========================================
```

выдается search_input[0].send_keys('+7 (911) 111-11-11')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Проверьте, что строка `search_input = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.form-group:nth-child(2) > .form-control')` возвращает не пустой список. Добавьте после нее, например, `print(len(search_input))`. Должен быть больше 0.

Comment: а как проверить, что строка Проверьте, что строка search_input = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.form-group:nth-child(2) > .form-control') возвращает не пустой список?

Comment: А вы дальше первого предложения прочли? Сделали, что я написал?

Comment: сделала, вот что получаю IndexError: list index out of range 0

Comment: А в консоли что-то появилось перед этим? Должно было быть число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

надо было find_element без s, то есть

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-group:nth-child(2) > .form-control').send_keys(
        '+7 (911) 111-11-11')
```